# How to download Google Compute engine ssh private key?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

how do you download the key as a ppk file to use on filezilla or another ftp program? there seems to be a lot of questions on how to do this, and I have not been able to figure it out... since I have the text of the key (from google cloud metadata), is there a way to copy/paste it into a txt file and then save it as a ppk??

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a private key in Compute Engine metadata. Google does not create a key for you.

Instead, create a new key and add the public key to the metadata. It will then be downloaded to your instance and you can use the private key you just generated to connect to the instance. Instructions to do this are at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys.